# how to use tag variable in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have a type object tag in cShapeLayerItem.Tag

here is the code

```
public class CShapeLayerItem
    {
        public CShape Shape;
        public long ID;
        Object _tag = null;
        public Object Tag { get { return _tag; } set { _tag = value; } }
        public DataRow Row;
        public CShapeLayer cShapeLayer = null;
        public CShapeLayerItem()
        {
        }
    }
```

here is CShapeLayerItem and tag value

[image]

when i try with cShapeLayerItem.Tag. there no link to skenarioID

[image: image2]

the question is how to get skenarioID value in tag 
and show in textbox txtSkenarioID.Text?
im new in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Tag` property is an `object`, so as with any object, you'll need to cast it back to whatever type is stored in there before you can access properties on it.

Assuming you've got an instance of `CEntitySkenario`, cast it to that (I'm also assuming the `skenarioID` property is accessible):

```
txtSkenarioID.Text = ((CEntitySkenario)cShapeLayerItem.Tag).skenarioID.ToString();
```

Comment: `txtSkenarioID.Text =((CEntitySkenario)cShapeLayerItem.Tag).skenarioID.ToString();` i try your code and now works . i try solve problem yesterday but now i find the answer. thanks @Grant